# Building Google Caliper

Tags: maven, guava, caliper

I'm trying to build google caliper on mac osx (10.9.5), using the latest git commit, and am running into the following issue:

```
/ExperimentingCaliperRun.java:[225,18] cannot find symbol
[ERROR] symbol:   method transformAsync(com.google.common.util.concurrent.ListenableFuture<capture#1 of ?>,<anonymous com.google.common.util.concurrent.AsyncFunction<java.lang.Object,com.google.caliper.runner.TrialResult>>)
[ERROR] location: class com.google.common.util.concurrent.Futures
```

I'm using Maven 3.2.5, java is currently set to 1.8 (update 71). I think it might have something to do with issues related to Guava 19.0, but I'm not very familiar with this to say for sure. Have others encountered this issue? Any quick fixes?

Comment: I gave a brief summary on [the Caliper issue you filed](https://github.com/google/caliper/issues/322#issuecomment-180417461). Sorry for the mess right now.

Comment: @ChrisPovirk no problem! Sorry about the duplicate, posted here first before it occurred to me to open an issue. Thanks for the prompt response

Comment: @ChrisPovirk ended up using 0.5 version (since I could download the jar etc from mvn with no issues). The only thing I'm having issues with is setting up memory measurements. Any pointers on this? Saw some old threads with similar issues to the ones I'm having, but the solution isn't stated there

Comment: Sorry, I don't know. I was in Caliper only to make some Guava-related changes :(